# Cursor vs. Start parameter in Scopus API

Tags: scopus, pybliometrics

I am working on a project that uses Scopus API to get document names or journal names under different scenarios. I am using *ScopusSearch* API (https://dev.elsevier.com/documentation/ScopusSearchAPI.wadl) and *SerialTitle* API (https://dev.elsevier.com/documentation/SerialTitleAPI.wadl) for the purpose.

However, the **total number of documents** I am able to retrieve using these API's is very few. I want to increase the number of documents being fetched. Now, I've been through the documentation of these API's a several times but I am confused with the use of *start* parameter and the *cursor* parameter.
Take for example, *ScopusSearch* API, under its *query params* section:

**start parameter** [image: use of start as query parameter]
**cursor parameter**[image: use of cursor]

Can someone please help me understand the difference between these two? And more specifically when to use the start and when to use the cursor parameter?

Comment: @ElsevierDevelopers Can you please help with this?

Comment: @Rob Well, I haven't.. these are the snippets from a web URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `pybliometrics`, as your tag suggests, then you don't need to care about this.

The basic idea behind this pagination (that's what you're after) is:

1. Run a query with unlimited number of results with `cursor` set to "*"
2. Set `start` to 0 and get the first `count` results
3. Set `start` to `start+count+1` and get the next `count` results
4. Repeat step 3 until all results are fetched

Comment: So you're saying every time we use `cursor` parameter, we have to specify `start` parameter along with it?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it doesn's make sense. It's like a book that they send you, but you have to retrieve it page by page.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply @MERose. But I am still confused at a point where with SerialSearch API I am using only 'start' parameter set to index from where I want to start my search, it fetches 200 results for me. It then gets updated and gets next 200. I am doing all of this without 'cursor' parameter. I still do not understand its need!

Comment: The API needs the cursor information filled to initiate pagination. If you provide `start` but not `cursor`, pybliometrics fills it for you.